# "Unable to locate an executable" when trying to install Docker compose plugin

Tags: docker, java, macintosh

I try to install Docker compose plugin in terminal for Mac but always that I try to do it terminal give this error:

```
Unable to locate an executable at "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-20.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/apt" (-1)
```

How can I resolve the problem?

Comment: Do you understand that the error message is telling you either that the file does not exist on your system or that it's inaccessible to the process you're running? Have you installed the named Java JDK there?